# What is the name for those images with quotes in them?

Tags: phrase-requests, image-identification

Googling for [picture quotes](https://www.google.com/q=picture+quotes) results in many images like this one:

[image: Every champion was once a contender that refused to give up]

It's not about motivation, it can be any type, like this one:

[image: Walking my fish, like a boss]

I believe there is a better word for this, but I can't remember it.

Comment: I think Jack Handey called them [*Deep Thoughts*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jack_Handey)

Comment: Not quite it, but [*caption*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/caption) may work. [Googling it](https://www.google.es/search?q=caption&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiizevp3ubKAhXIPBoKHereBdcQ_AUIBygB&biw=1280&bih=699) returns several of those images, but there's generally an image and a text explaining it (like [this one](http://www.pincaption.com/media/gallery/original/walking-my-fish-caption-image-139485605055209839.jpg)), not that the text *is* the image.

Comment: From reading just the question/title, I thought you were looking for the word *meme*. But no, you're looking for what we call inspirational images with inspirational quotes, I guess.

Comment: Well I've heard them called mainly two things *inspirational quotes* or simply *rubbish*

Comment: I guess I chose the wrong picture, as it's not necessarily about motivation. It can be any image, picture or illustration that has a quote in it, like the one @Yay linked to.

Comment: There should be a name for these things but there isn't.  The best name I have seen is "demotivational poster" (because they are all so banal).  Google it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These images are one type of **meme** aka **Internet meme**

*EDIT: perhaps as mentioned in Tim Ward's comment that is not specific enough as not limited to 'quotation images'*

Anyway quoting  http://www.macmillandictionary.com/buzzword/entries/meme.html

> *noun [countable*]
> a concept or idea that spreads very quickly via the Internet
>
> ...
>
> a piece of information that spreads very rapidly across a large number of Internet users. It's a bit like the online equivalent of an inside joke, a fashionable, attention-grabbing concept that a large number of Internet users become aware of. A meme often takes the form of a hyperlink, propagated via e-mail, blogs, social networking, instant messaging, etc. like a kind of virtual Chinese whisper. **A meme might be a joke or quotation, a rumour or simple fact, an image, piece of video, or even a particular website** – virtually any titbit that can be passed from one person to another via electronic communication. A key facet of a meme is that it is voluntary, a communication which spreads from one place to the next without any kind of compulsion or automation. ...

Comment: I think you are right.  *But* 'meme' is widely used for many different things.  The OP is looking for a specifying name for this particular version of this meme.

Comment: I just picked one picture that I thought would qualify. It's not about motivation, so I've added another picture. I guess "meme" is what I was looking for, even if that is broader than just pictures, and even if the picture has not gone viral.

Comment: No.  A meme is just a generic term for an idea or concept that spreads quickly.  It could be a belief, thought, joke, piece of music, etc.  The items in the original post might be a meme or might not.

Answer (score 4):

The first picture is an example of a [inspirational quote](http://theultralinx.com/2016/01/awesome-quotes-posters-pictures/).  It fits in the broader category of [motivational posters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motivational_poster).

The second picture is an example of an Internet [meme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meme) (a portmanteau of "mime" and "gene", coined by Richard Dawkins). Specifically, a meme that involves an animal is sometimes called an [advice animal](https://www.reddit.com/r/AdviceAnimals).

Comment: I picked the wrong image. It wasn't about motivation, it was about the picture with a quote in it. Motivational posters - nice to see and it's close.

Comment: You've changed your question; I've amended my answer.

Comment: Note that meme is broader than just text-on-photos, though. It is any kind of seemingly self-replicating idea.

Answer (score 3):

At this point, the strongest contender for what to call them without using "meme" is "image macro." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_macro

Comment: I think this is actually the most accurate term for what the poster is asking about.

Comment: I think it's the correct answer, and the only one here that's not ballpark. The others should be comments at best.

Answer (score 2):

***Commonplace clips*** perhaps. By sharing the ones we like on Facebook and such we are, effectively, making collections of 'commonplaces' (*striking or notable passages, noted, for reference or use, in a book of common places*, OED) for ourselves and our friends.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commonplace_book